# Keeping syntax color foreground in vim search highlight

Tags: vim, full-text-search, vim-syntax-highlighting

In Vim, is it possible to get the foreground text in a highlighted search match to keep the colors specified by my colorscheme?
If possible, I'd like to customize just the background color of the match
(`hi Search ctermbg=BLAH`)
and keep the foreground colors the same as they were before the match.
I suspect that this isn't possible with the built-in hlsearch, but I figured I'd check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually exactly how it works, if you clear the `Search` highlight group beforehand. Following the ideas outlined in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/romainl/379904f91fa40533175dfaec4c833f2f) by romainl, you could do the following:

```
augroup MyColors
    autocmd!
    autocmd ColorScheme * highlight clear Search
                      \ | highlight Search ctermbg={blah}
augroup END
colorscheme foo
```

Note that in order for the autocmd to take effect you must set your colorscheme ***after*** your `autocmd`.